# Overlapping ranks - Creating a block diagram

Tags: block, graphviz, diagram, ranking

I nearly spent the whole day trying to get a block diagram out of Graphviz. The biggest problem seems to be that I've got vertical as well as horizontal ranking. Easier shown than explained, so here is how the diagram should look:

[image: block_diagram]

This is my Dot-Code so far:

```
digraph block_diagram 
{
  graph [ splines=ortho, rankdir=TB];
  node [shape=box, style=filled, fontname=Arial];

  layer_0 [style="rounded,filled", fillcolor="#99ccff", width=15, height=1, label="Layer 0"];

  layer_1 [shape=box, width=5, height=1, label="Layer 1"];
  //emptybox [shape=box,height=1, label=""];
  layer_1_1 [shape=box, width=5, height=1, label="Layer 1_1"];
  layer_2 [shape=box, width=5, height=1, label="Layer 2"];
  layer_3 [shape=box, width=5, height=1, label="Layer 3"];
  layer_4 [shape=box, width=5, height=1, label="Layer 4"];

  application [shape=box, width=3, height=5, label="Application"];

  layer_0 -> { layer_1 application };
  layer_0 -> layer_1 -> layer_1_1 -> layer_2 -> layer_3 -> layer_4;
  application -> { layer_2 layer_3 layer_4 };
}
```

It looks like this -

[image: img]

I tried to group the nodes and rank them, but in the end all have the same rank and the diagram just looks wrong.

I don't know what to do anymore, and I hope someone can help me.

P.S.: I also don't know to create a shape like 'Layer 1'

Comment: I don't think you could (or should) do that with graphviz. graphviz is strong at organising nodes optimally which is in direct contrast to the desire of the user to control the layout in detail. I would use LaTeX / tikz but there may be other / better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Summary: This answer presents a variant using auxiliary nodes, **still looking for a variant with no extra nodes and clusters**.

If you create several invisible nodes within a cluster, you can get desired visual behavior, as in this image:
[image: block diagram with showed nodes made by graphviz dot]
This is possible through the use of the attribute [`newrank=true`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/newrank/) to graph and `{ rank=same; nodename1; nodename2; ... }` for **horizontal alignment** desired nodes. To hide auxiliary nodes, you need to give them an attribute [`style=invis`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/style/), to hide cluster's borders add attribute `color=none` to cluster.

For **vertical alignment**, [group](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/group/) the desired nodes by giving them an attribute `group=g1`, here `g1` is your custom name for column of nodes.

*Layer 1* and *Layer 1_1* nodes can be created as [table cells](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#sides-example).

Bi-directional edges created with `dir=both`.

To make the line end at the cluster boundary, I used attribute [`compound=true`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/docs/attrs/compound/) for graph and `lhead`, `ltail` for edge.

Final image:
[image: block diagram with hidden nodes made by graphviz dot]
Script:

```
digraph block_diagram  {
    graph [
        newrank=true,
        ranksep=0,
        nodesep=0,
        splines=ortho,
        compound=true,
        fontname="Arial" ];
    node [
        shape=box,
        style=filled,
        fontname="Arial",
        fontsize=14 ];

    subgraph cluster_0{
        fillcolor="#99ccff"
        style="rounded, filled"
        layer_0 [
                label=<<B>Layer 0</B>>,
                fillcolor=none,
                shape=none
                width=1 ];
        a1 [group=g1 width=1.5 style=invis]
        a2 [group=g2 width=1.5 style=invis]
    }

    subgraph cluster_1_1 {
        color=none;
        layer_1 [
            group=g1,
            fillcolor=none,
            shape=none,
            margin=0,
            label=  <<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellborder="1">
                <tr>
                    <td width="40" height="30" fixedsize="true" BGCOLOR="#ccffff" sides="TL"></td>
                    <td width="80" height="30" fixedsize="true" BGCOLOR="#ccffff" sides="TRB" ALIGN="LEFT"><B>Layer 1</B></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="40" height="30" fixedsize="true" BGCOLOR="#ccffff" sides="RBL"></td>
                    <td COLSPAN="2" width="72" height="26" fixedsize="true" BGCOLOR="#ccffff" sides="TBRL" VALIGN="BOTTOM"><B>Layer 1_1</B></td>
                </tr></table>>]
        layer_2 [
            group=g1,
            label=<<B>Layer 2</B>>,
            fillcolor ="#ccffff",
            width=1.6 ];
        } 
        
    layer_underline [
        group=g1,
        label="",
        margin=0;
        shape=underline,
        fillcolor=none,
        width=2,
        height=0 ];
            
    subgraph cluster_1_2{
        color=none;
        layer_3 [
            group=g1,
            label=<<B>Layer 3</B>>,
            fillcolor="#ccff99",
            width=1.6 ];
        layer_4 [
            group=g1,
            label=<<B>Layer 4</B>>,
            fillcolor="#ccff99",
            width=1.6 ];
    }
    
    subgraph cluster_2 {
        style=filled;
        fillcolor="#dde6ed"
        b1 [group=g2 style=invis]
        application [
            group=g2,
            label=<<B>Application</B>>,
            shape=none
            fillcolor=none
            width=2 ];
        b2 [group=g2 style=invis]
    }
    
    a1 -> layer_0  [style=invis]
    layer_0 -> a2 [style=invis]
    a1 -> layer_1 [minlen=3 ltail="cluster_0" lhead="cluster_1_1" dir="both" color="#99ccff" penwidth=5 arrowsize=.5]
    a2 -> b1 [ltail="cluster_0" lhead="cluster_2" dir=both color="#99ccff" penwidth=5 arrowsize=.5]
    
    layer_1 -> layer_2 [style=invis];
    layer_2 -> layer_underline [ color="#99ccff" penwidth=5 arrowsize=.5 dir=back ltail="cluster_1_1"]
    layer_underline -> layer_3 [ color="#99ccff" penwidth=5 arrowsize=.5 lhead="cluster_1_2"]
    layer_3 -> layer_4 [style=invis]
    
    b1 -> application [style=invis]
    application -> b2 [style=invis]
    
    layer_4 -> b2 [color="#99ccff" penwidth=5 arrowsize=.5 ltail="cluster_1_2" lhead="cluster_2" dir=both]
    layer_2 -> application [color="#99ccff" penwidth=5 arrowsize=.5 ltail="cluster_1_1" lhead="cluster_2" dir=both]
    
    { rank=same; layer_4; b2 }
    { rank=same; layer_1; b1 }
    { rank=same; layer_underline; application }
    { rank=same; a1; layer_0; a2 }
}
```